# Getting unique models in nested Many To Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi fellow StackOverflow users!

I'm struggling on a pretty simple task, and I'd be very greetful if one of you could help me out.
I have 3 models with nested Many To Many Relationship.

My first model is **Wave** that has a M2M relationship with *Employee* :

#### Wave.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Wave extends Model
{

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee');
    }
```

**Employee** that has a Many To Many with *Wave* and another Many To Many with *Expertise*

#### Employee.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{

    public function waves()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wave');
    }

    public function expertises()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Expertise');
    }
```

Finally my *Expertise* model with a many to many with *Employee*:

#### Expertise.php

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Expertise extends Model
{

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Employee');
    }
```

What I'd like to achieve here is create a custom property on **Wave** to get all distinct **expertises** that **employees** assigned to this **wave** possess.

It would look a one dimensional collection of distinct *expertises*.

It doesn't seem very complicated but I tried many things and can't get it working.

Last thing I tried was querying Expertise model using **with** and **withPivotIn**  but without success:

#### Wave.php

```php
    public function getExpertisesAttribute()
    {
        $employees = $this->employees;
        $expertises = Expertise::with('employees', function($q) use($employees) {
            $q->wherePivotIn('employee_id', $employees->pluck('id')->toArray());
        });
        return $expertises;
    }
```

I'm getting an error while running this query:

`PHP Warning:  mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /Users/Kaz/lab/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 107`

FYI i'm using Laravel 5.8 on PHP 7.2

Thank you very much for reading this and I hope you'll be able to give me some help because I'm feeling a bit stuck and still it seems like an easy thing to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method from Laravel.   This method will enforce returning only `Expertises` that have an `employee` relationship with those `employees` contained within the wave object.

Give this a try.  Tweak as necessary, but this should get you where you wish to go:

```
$employees = $this->employees;
$employees_ids = $employees->pluck('id')->toArray();
$expertises = Expertise::with('employees')->whereHas('employees', function ($query) use ($employees_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('employees.id', $employees_ids);
})->get();

dd($expertises);
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, thank you very much! I already used whereHas in the past but totally forgot about it, thank you again :) !